# Using compactness method to prove the existence of a pathwise solution to an SPDE

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, compactness

For given initial data $u_0\in H^k$ for some $k$, I want to prove the existence of solution to some PDE with multiplicative white noise. I modify the SPDE by regularizing it and then use the compactness method(finding a subsequence) to obtain the solution. What I want to prove is that for $a.e.\omega\in\Omega$, there is a $$u(\omega,t,x)\in C([0,T]; H^k)\ for\ some\ T>0.$$

Let us consider the pathwise solution. I mean, the stochastic basis is given in advance.

Even though for fixed $\omega\in\Omega$, I have found one subsequence of the approximate solution which is strong convergence in the space and time variables, i.e, strong convergence in $x$ and $t$, I can not obtain that for $a.e.\omega\in\Omega$, there is a solution because for different $\omega\in\Omega$, the convergent subsequence is different.

So, what condition should be verified to obtain that for $a.e.\omega\in\Omega$, there is a solution $u(\omega,t,x)$?

Comment: A cheap comment (but it depends strongly on the PDE you're looking): a possible way out is to establish uniqueness of the solution for each of your random events $\omega$ ; then the whole sequence converges

Answer (score -1):

This type of existence of first fixing an omega and then obtaining a solution is pretty standard eg. see ["Regularization by noise and flows of solutions for a stochastic heat equation"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02553).

Is there some particular reason you need matching subsequences, which seems unlikely if starting with random initial data too?

For some recent results in stochastic pdes with multiplicative noise see: [A Wong-Zakai theorem for stochastic PDEs](https://www.hairer.org/papers/WongZakai.pdf)

Comment: I see a downvote, any feedback is welcome.